# Connecting flight time at AMS

Tags: air-travel, transit, short-connections

I am flying OTP (Bucharest Henri Coandă, RO) - AMS (Amsterdam Schipol, NL) - SLC (Salt Lake City, US).

Is 1 hour and 5 minutes enough time to make my flight at AMS to SLC?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if they allow you to book this on a single ticket, then it is enough time. Having said that, the airport in Amsterdam is huge, so you shouldn't waste time getting to your gate.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. For an accurate answer, we need to know more about the itinerary: is this booked as a single ticket, or as two separate itineraries? What are the airlines involved? Do you have checked baggage? What is your citizenship? Please [edit] your post to include such information.

Comment: This could be cutting it close. Gate for departing flight will close sooner than the 1.05 timeframe and there are many other things to consider (it's been long ago since I flew to the USA - don't have a clue about pre-checks these days). AMS is big but it depends a lot on which gates are used for arriving and departing planes. I would only count on this if it was sold as a single ticket and even then a small delay could end up in missing the connection.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify airlines but that's OK, I know what airlines are flying these routes... SLC is Delta 4th largest hub, while AMS is KLM's main hub and they also happen to be in alliance (working together closer than normal, even for alliance) so let's check the GDS for MCT at AMS for them:

KL-DL II   .50

you are cutting this awfully close. Doable, yes, especially because last time I did something like this the security was at the gate so if you got in line they didn't really leave without you but as I just copied, even the official connection time is 50 minutes and that's always optimistic.